# Personalized thanks message on contact form

Tags: php, forms

I have got the following code to make a contact form works:

```
<?php
session_name("fancyform");
session_start();


$_SESSION['n1'] = rand(1,20);
$_SESSION['n2'] = rand(1,20);
$_SESSION['expect'] = $_SESSION['n1']+$_SESSION['n2'];


if(isset($_SESSION['sent']))
{
    $success='<p>GThanks for contacting us! We'll reply you asap!</p>';
    $css='<style type="text/css">.demo-form{display:none;}.thanks{display:block;}</style>';

unset($_SESSION['sent']);
}
?>
```

The problem there is that I would want to add a personalized message.

Example: My name is Xavi, so if I type on the name field: Xavi, I will get a reply like this one: Thanks for contacting us Xavi! We'll reply you asap!

I dont know how to solve it, since I tried the following values but without any result:

```
&name, 'name', ['name'], '['name']'
```

Contact form label:

```
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" id="name" name="name" data-parsley-trigger="change" required tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['post']['name']) ? $_SESSION['post']['name'] : ''); ?>" >
```

Comment: This `if(isset($_SESSION['sent']))` where are you defining it? Plus, check your syntax. SO's syntax highlighting is showing something that's "out of whack"; it being `We'll` so escape it `We\'ll`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same place where you define `$_SESSION['sent'] = true`, add another session variable to store the name:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
```

Then, use it in your message:

```
$success="<p>GThanks for contacting us " . htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['name']) . "! We'll reply you asap!</p>";
```

Side note: you have an issue with the quotes because you wrap the string in single quotes, but use another single quote in the word `We'll`.

Comment: OP should escape the quote instead `We\'ll`

Comment: Escaping or changing to double quotes to wrap the literal is personal preference. Neither is necessarily better or worse than the other.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. Using single quotes inside what the echo is wrapped in, being single quotes will cause a parse error `$success='<p>GThanks for contacting us! We'll reply you asap!</p>';` which should be `$success='<p>GThanks for contacting us! We\'ll reply you asap!</p>';` which is what the OP is using right now. Although it won't fix the code, it will nonetheless throw an error.

Comment: I fixed it in the answer by changing to double quotes to wrap the string... escaping would also fix it as you say.

Comment: This would work out a bit better `$success="<p>GThanks for contacting us! We'll reply you asap!</p>";` --- In doing so, would save the OP "one" keystroke (lol) ;-) wow, one keystroke. Hey, every little bit counts! Cheers

Comment: Why are you telling me about double quotes or a parse error when the original answer already included a fix for that, plus a side note about it?

Comment: My mistake. However I was also making a "sidenote" ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your time guys, I really appreciate it, also it works perfectly as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can access to the form data by using the `$_REQUEST` array :

```
echo $_REQUEST['name'];
```